Program to find three cubes that sum to a fourth cube
I'm writing a Rust program that finds the "first five cubes that can be written as the sum of three distinct nonzero cubes", e.g. 216 = 6^3 = 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3. The function looks like this:
fn find_cubes(max_cube: i32) -> HashMap<i32, (i32, i32, i32)> {
    let mut cube_triples: HashMap<i32, (i32, i32, i32)> = HashMap::new();
    let cubes = (1..=max_cube).map(|num| num * num * num).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
    let cube_set: HashSet<i32> = HashSet::from_iter(cubes.iter().cloned());
    for target_cube in &cubes {
        for (index, first_cube) in cubes.iter().enumerate() {
            for second_cube in &cubes[index..] {
                let third_cube = target_cube - first_cube - second_cube;
                if !cube_set.contains(&third_cube) || first_cube + second_cube + third_cube > *target_cube {
                    continue;
                }
                if first_cube + second_cube + third_cube == *target_cube {
                    cube_triples.insert(*target_cube, (*first_cube, *second_cube, third_cube));
                }
                if cube_triples.len() == 5 {
                    return cube_triples
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cube_triples
}

max_cube can be adjusted if not enough cubes are found in a given range.
How can this code be optimised? Using a very rudimentary timing function, it takes ~0.1 seconds to run, which is twice as slow as an equivalent program in Python.

Could you add the code you are using to time this? It would make it easier for me to make reproducible suggestions.

fn main() {
    use std::time::Instant;
    let now = Instant::now();
    let nums = find_cubes(1000);
    let elapsed = now.elapsed();
}


Please [edit] the code into the question, comments are ephemeral

You can save quite a bit of time by (1) breaking on the first satisfactory triple for each target_cube and (2) expanding cubes iteratively instead of all at the start. For readability, I would also isolate |num| num * num * num into a helper function. For example:
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn do_cube(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x * x * x
}

fn find_cubes_new(n: usize) -> HashMap<i32, (i32, i32, i32)> {
    let mut cube_triples: HashMap<i32, (i32, i32, i32)> = HashMap::new();

    let mut d = 4;
    let mut cubes = (0..=d).map(do_cube).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
    let mut cube_set: HashSet<i32> = HashSet::from_iter(cubes.iter().cloned());

    while cube_triples.len() < n {
        let cube_d = cubes[d as usize];
        let mut found = false;

        for a in 1..(d as usize) {
            let cube_a = cubes[a];
            for b in (a+1)..(d as usize) {
                let cube_b = cubes[b];
                let cube_c = cube_d - (cube_a + cube_b);
                if cube_set.contains(&cube_c) {
                    // a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = d^3; 0 < a < b < c < d
                    cube_triples.insert(cube_d, (cube_a, cube_b, cube_c));
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if found {
                break;
            }
        }

        d += 1;
        let new_cube_d = do_cube(d);
        cubes.push(new_cube_d);
        cube_set.insert(new_cube_d);
    }

    cube_triples
}

fn main() { 
    use std::time::Instant; 
    let now = Instant::now(); 
    let nums = find_cubes_new(5); 
    let elapsed = now.elapsed(); 
    println!("{:?}", elapsed);
    for (cube_d, (cube_a, cube_b, cube_c)) in &nums {
        println!("{} + {} + {} = {}", cube_a, cube_b, cube_c, cube_d);
    }
}

Note that this iterative approach means we don't need max_cubes as a parameter - instead, I use n to represent the number of desired cubes that can be written as the sum of three distinct positive cubes. Here is the output I got:
189.38µs
1 + 216 + 512 = 729
216 + 512 + 1000 = 1728
27 + 64 + 125 = 216
8 + 1728 + 4096 = 5832
27 + 1000 + 5832 = 6859

Here is the output from using the provided find_cubes:
2.172391621s
512 + 1000 + 216 = 1728
64 + 125 + 27 = 216
1728 + 4096 + 8 = 5832
216 + 512 + 1 = 729
27 + 1000 + 5832 = 6859


Nice improvement. I think you could extract cube_d_a = cube_d - cube_a from the inner loop as an invariant to save an operation on each loop. And instead of using found you could use a labeled loop: 'outer:... --> break 'outer;

@Falco: There's a good chance the compiler is already hoisting cube_d - cube_a, to be fair :)

The algorithm you're using is O(n3) time, since it contains three nested loops over your list of cubes. You can reduce this to O(n2) time at the cost of O(n2) space, by caching the sums of cubes instead of just the cubes. A few other improvements:

Instead of storing the cubes in a vector, you can generate them each time you want to iterate over all cubes in some range. Multiplication is fast. To avoid code duplication, define a new function cube_range which returns an iterator of pairs like (x, x_cube).
As @Justin Chang notes, we can do away with the max_cube parameter by just generating until enough results are found.
The inner loop doesn't need to consider candidates which are greater than or equal to target, since all the summands are positive.
Since uniqueness is now achieved by iterating over target_cube first, we no longer need a hashmap to ensure each target is only found once. Using a vector for the results instead means we get the results in order, which is nice.
It's more convenient to output the numbers themselves, rather than their cubes.
Use u32 instead of i32; none of these numbers will be negative.
Use .copied() on iterators of integers, so you don't need to write * everywhere. Copying integers is very cheap.

fn cube_range(x_range: impl IntoIterator<Item = u32>) -> impl Iterator<Item = (u32, u32)> {
    x_range.into_iter()
        .map(|x| (x, x * x * x))
}

fn find_cubes(count: usize) -> Vec<(u32, u32, u32, u32)> {
    let mut cube_pair_sums: HashMap<u32, (u32, u32)> = HashMap::new();
    let mut result: Vec<(u32, u32, u32, u32)> = Vec::new();
    
    for (target, target_cube) in cube_range(1..) {
        // Check if `target_cube` is a sum of three cubes
        for (x, x_cube) in cube_range(1..target) {
            let rest_sum = target_cube - x_cube;
            if let Some((y, z)) = cube_pair_sums.get(&rest_sum).copied() {
                result.push((target, x, y, z));
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if result.len() == count { break; }
        
        // Update `cube_pair_sums` to include cubes up to `target_cube`
        let x = target;
        let x_cube = target_cube;
        for (y, y_cube) in cube_range(1..=x) {
            let sum = x_cube + y_cube;
            cube_pair_sums.insert(sum, (x, y));
        }
    }
    
    result
}

On my laptop this finds the first five solutions in ~10µs (in a release build with optimisations enabled), compared to ~70ms for your original code with max_cube = 1000, as described in your comment.
Actually, most of the running time of your code is spent by iterating all the way up to max_cube in each loop, so the time taken by your code depends strongly on choosing max_cube to be low enough while still getting a correct answer. Setting max_cube = 19 (the lowest possible for finding five distinct results) gives a time of ~34µs for your original code.
For comparison, Justin Chang's code is marginally faster on my laptop for count = 5 (~8µs), but the above algorithm is faster for count >= 7.

Is rust doing some caching on the cube_range iterator, or will it calculate the same multiplications multiple times for each number?

@Falco: It will compute every time. A multiplication is 3 CPU cycles, so assuming good pipelining, it may only take 6 CPU cycles.

@MatthieuM. that is still max_cubes! * 6 cycles so O(n²) for the multiplications, I think an array to cache the values could be a lot faster.

@Falco: Your notation is confusing. The number of cubes calculated is irrelevant: if you didn't compute them, but looked them up in array, you'd still perform the same number of look-ups. Therefore, the only difference is cost of calculation vs cost of look-up. And the cost of look-up is... unclear. If you have a pre-populated array, it's very low. Say 1 cycle. But how do you get an appropriately-sized pre-populated array? Nobody knows. If for each access you check whether it's in bounds, and if not populate the array on the fly, suddenly it may cost quite a bit more than 1 cycle... (cont)

@Falco: (cont) ... and especially, unlike the cubes which can be calculated in parallel -- multiple iterations of the loop can be done in parallel -- the lazy-population of the array would prevent the CPU from doing that. If you have a better solution with a pre-populated array -- I'd maybe try exponential growth, skipping already checked triplets -- then, yes, maybe it'd be faster. But it's not obviously faster.

@Falco I don't know where you got a factorial from.

@kaya3 you are right it's n*(n-1) but still O(n²) operations.

@MatthieuM. since the outer loop sets an upper bound for the inner loops the array does not need to be pre populated, it only needs reserved memory with a fitting size. The outer loop can do the calculation once and the inner loops can just do a look-up without bounds check (because the inner loops are bounded to an index smaller/equal than the outer loop).

@Falco It is O(n^2) however you slice it, and my answer says so. That's better than O(n^3), which the OP and other answer are. Changing two multiplications into one array access obviously will not change the asymptotic behaviour of the algorithm. The question is only whether two multiplications is faster than one array access. I suspect there is no difference in practice, except for the cost of populating the array. As Matthieu said, if you think you can improve the performance by caching the results of integer multiplication, then go ahead and write an answer.

@MatthieuM. it seems the array access does indeed not make a big difference. Benchmarking in the online playground is to unstable to provide conclusive results
